# Browser request to server only one stylesheet or all css files(Which is @import in main stylesheet)?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to "@import" importing a CSS files within single "style.CSS" which is use on main html file in head tag like "link href". then Use firebug to inspect elements and see only "style.css" applied to it, I wanted to know browser request to server only one time for "style.css" OR for every css which is @import in "style.css" This components include in "style.css"?

This components include in "style.css"

```
@import url("main.css");
@import url("colorzilla.css");
@import url("mainbox.css");

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }

html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; }
body, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }

::-moz-selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

Comment: Well, do the styles of the imported file get applied on the page?

Comment: I wanted to know browser request to server only one time for "style.css" OR for every css which is @import in "style.css"

This components include in "style.css"

Comment: @user2045753: Every file, otherwise, how would it apply those @imports?

Comment: The browser requests the next stylesheet after it has downloaded and parsed the one containing the `@import` statement. It is better to avoid this and use `link` tags for each stylesheet so that they are all downloaded in parallel.

Comment: Check this interesting article about LINK and @import : http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser sends a separate request for each imported stylesheet. Also the same for JavaScript files.

To avoid this, you can use a minifier on server side, which (besides minifying) combines the different stylesheets (and JavaScripts), so 1 request will be enough for all the CSS and 1 for all the JS content. Then they are cached.

Number of requests will become more important if you use HTTPS, when there are additional handshake and overhead at each request, due to SSL/TLS.